# Use hardware keyboard with rdp

Tags: keyboard, raspberry-pi, remote-desktop

I'm running xrdp on my RPi, and it works how it's supposed to, but since the keyboard on iOS behaves weird in Microsoft's rdp app, I would like to be able to use my iPhone/iPad as screen (+ mouse) and use a small bluetooth keyboard, connected to the RPi, to type.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: I think [x2x](https://github.com/dottedmag/x2x) would let you do that, but I don't know how to set it up.